# Access routes inside route group via helper

Tags: routes, laravel-6

I have a route group like the following.

**Route**

```
Route::namespace('AdminPannel')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/',function(){
        return view('adminpannel.index');
    })->name('adminpannelindex');
    Route::get('locations', 'LocationsController@index')->name('locations');

});
```

However, I can't access the "adminpannelindex" route via my helper.

```
Route('adminpannelindex');
```

**Error**

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
>   Route [adminpannelroot.adminpannelindex] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\khino\resources\views\adminpannel\layouts\sidebar-right.blade.php)

Comment: You can run an `artisan` command to see a list of your available routes, **including their names**: `php artisan route:list`. That should be your go-to whenever you get this error.

Comment: Thank you @tim-lewis
Solved

Comment: What is the update on this ? Can you please revert back ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Route
>   [adminpannelroot.adminpannelindex] not defined.

```
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'AdminPannel',
    'as'        => 'adminpannelroot.'
],function(){
    Route::get('/',function(){
        return view('adminpannel.index');
    })->name('adminpannelindex');
    Route::get('locations', 'LocationsController@index')->name('locations');
});
```

Now you can call,

```
adminpannelroot.adminpannelindex
```

and

```
adminpannelroot.locations
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your route would be:

```
'AdminPannel.adminpannelindex';
```